# Substring is bash script to matching correctly

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that has a filename and a string contained within a file and I want to compare a substring from the file against the filename(tar.gz) to see if they match or not.

```
substr=$(echo "$(cat /home/user/configrc | grep Version)" | cut -d '_' -f4-5)
xfile="/home/user/data_1806_01.tar.gz"
echo $substr
echo $xfile
echo "Is $substr in $xfile"

if [ "$xfile" == *"$substr"* ]; then echo "Match"; else echo "No Match"; fi
```

the output is as follows

```
DD_DATA_AB_1806_01
1806_01
/home/user/data_1806_01.tar.gz
 in /home/user/data_1806_01.tar.gz
No Match
```

I can't get a match to occur, 1806_01 should have the substring match in DD_DATA_AB_1806_01.
Also what is strange is that the line - echo "Is $substr in $xfile" does not get printed out properly - "Is $substr" or "Is 1806_01" is missing

Is there some sort of termination that i need at the end of substr??

The file configrc contains the line Version=DD_DATA_AB_1806_01

I have looked at many examples online but can't see what I am doing wrong.... such a simple problem....

Thank you very much
:)

Centos 7.2

Comment: Does `/home/user/configrc` have DOS-style (CRLF) line endings?

Comment: It may do. I believe the file could have been created in windows - is there a way I can tell?

Comment: Firstly, you don't need to use `cat` because `grep Version /home/user/configrc` will send it to standard output. Also, your string doesn't match because it's printing `DD_DATA_AB_1806_01` as the value of `$substr` which doesn't match `1806_01` which is the value of `$xfile` because it's not piping it into the `cut` command. Even if it worked, it still wouldn't match because you set `_` as a delimiter with the `cut` command so printing fields 4 and 5 will give you `1806 01` which isn't `1806_01`.

Comment: dos2unix allowed the line "Is 1806_01 in /home/user/data_1806_01.tar.gz". Still didn't match on substring thou

Comment: That makes more sense but it still doesn't match because you set `$xfile` to `/home/user/data_1806_01.tar.gz`. You'll have to print the `1806_01` form that to get a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you don't need `echo` and `cat` to `grep` for the string and you need two brackets for this type of comparison:

```
substr=$(grep 'Version' /home/user/configrc | cut -d '_' -f4-5)
xfile="/home/user/data_1806_01.tar.gz"

if [[ "$xfile" == *"$substr"* ]]; then
  echo "Match"
else
  echo "No Match"
fi
```

Comment: don't need grep either:  `substr=$(awk -F_  -v OFS=_ '/Version/ {print $4, $5}')`